# Closely coupled memory in Synopsys ARC processors

Tags: embedded, ram

I am studying about Synopsys ARC EM processors (EM4 in particular). And I came across what they call as Closely Coupled Memory (CCM).

According to their documents this a single cycle access RAM (capacity up to 2MB), which is used to store both instructions and data. In EM4, CCM is used without a cache memory or a scratchpad memory. And this is not even a type of Tightly Coupled Memory (TCM) as far as I understand.

I wanted to find out how this memory can be this fast, but until now I haven't been successful. (I guessed it's hard to be an SRAM because of the large capacity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems off-topic for StackOverflow.

However, "closely coupled memory" seems (to me) to be marketing-speak for "on-chip memory". SRAM can be very fast - unlike DRAM where addresses are multiplexed adding need for multiplexing, static RAM decodes from the full address bus and can work as fast as the logic gates in the silicon can address the storage locations. 2MB is perfectly in-scope for SRAM. EM6 has cache - so the choice is up to the designer whether to pay premium for (presumably) better performance of EM6, while also not precluding the cost-conscious market which the EM4 is aimed at. The term "tightly coupled memory" seems basically to be another (marketing) term for on-chip memory, used to distinguish it from "bus-based systems" where memory would be off-chip, slowing things down, taking more power, taking more board space, etc.

Comment: Very sorry about that @barny. I am new to StackOverflow, and I saw several questions and answers on ARM TCM on the site. So I thought it would be okay. Thanks for the quick answer. By the way, since cache is also SRAM wouldn't implementing a 2MB SRAM for CCM be more expensive than implementing cache? (maximum size of cache in EM6 is 32KB)

Comment: I assume not - presumably the cache works at the full CPU speed, whereas the 2M RAM is slower (but still has advantages over external memory)

Comment: Okay. But they claim that the CCM has 1 cycle access time. Doesn't that mean the CCM operates at a similar speed. Pardon me if this is a noob question.

Comment: Don't know - the datasheets don't seem to be easily accessible. There must be some advantage to the cache, perhaps access to instruction and data memories can't happen at the same time and instruction hits in the cache allow "simultaneous" instruction/data access.

Comment: Thanks @barny. I'll look into that

Comment: 1) Don't answer off-topiic questions! 2) CCM is partially marketing, but actually it has some truth in it. It is not just on-chip memory and most CPUs with CCM have larger normal SRAM in addition. And this is as simple as DRAM vs. SRAM. DRAM is typically way faster than SRAM when it comes to linear throughput.